# How to combine rows in mysql stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Like this two rows, I want them get stored in a variable and combine them together. Is it possible?

I haven't tried anything because I am yet to understand mysql functions.

[image]

[image]

Expected result:

> ```
> lookingFor, spec_criteria_total_clicks, spec_cri, cost, clicks
> 9, 16, 10, 445, 465
> 3, 16, 4, 146, 365
> ```

Another quick question, is there a way to store ids in array in mysql declare?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @P.Salmon i updated my question

Comment: I am unclear where the 2 rows come from - are they in the same table, seperate tables or coming from someplace else? BTW sql does not do arrays.

Comment: I did some if conditions in mysql stored procedures, SELECT * FROM performance WHERE (lots of conditions) and then  SELECT * FROM performance WHERE (lots of conditions). Yes they are both on same table.

Comment: You can combine sql queries using UNION or UNION ALL but if your queries are executed within if statements in your stored procedure (not function) then it looks like your only option would be to create a table or temporary table and insert from each select but without a more comprehensive  example of what you are trying to do (and I mean more than 2 sample rows) it's difficult to say for sure.

Comment: @P.Salmon what im doing right now is what your saying. the temporary creating table. Im doing `create table table_name`.

Comment: @P.Salmon my solution is `CREATE TEMPORARY`. would u like to answer it? I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already experienced in mysql stored procedures. Declaring an array variable in mysql procedure is impossible. What you must do is use either one of this:

> - CREATE TABLE
> - CREATE TEMPORARY
> - CREATE VIEW

Try and research on this keywords and you decide which one to use, make comparisons which one is fastest and more convenient for your case.

Comment: I am already using CREATE TABLE and will probably shift to VIEW or TEMPORARY. We have the same thoughts. Anyways, thanks for answering.

Comment: Glad I could help!